# How to access public images from my own instagram account, business page, via Angular

Tags: angular, instagram, instagram-api

We have a business account on Instagram. We would like to be able to post photos to Instagram and have them also appear on our website. I am looking for a little help getting started accessing the photos on Instagram via our website. More specifically, how do I create the user access token to access the API end points? Do I need to create an "app" and go through the review process? I find the documentation lacking this information.

I am using Angular 6 for the UI and ASP.Net Core for the API.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would start here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/ and then post more specific questions once you have started.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have struggled for days trying to figure out how to create the user access token. All of the documentation I have read leads me in circles. I literally just want to pull the images from our business page feed and display them on our website. Do I need to create and "app" and have it go through the review process? Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to embed photos from your companies Instagram account you shouldn't need an access token. From https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/

> To embed Instagram content you need to first visit the post on the web and get the embed code. Go to the post URL if you have it, or you can search for the username on Instagram.com, visit their profile, and then click the post to expand it. Click the more [...] button and select "Embed". This will open a dialog where you can get the HTML embed code. Simply copy the code into your website and the embedded post will automatically load. By default the post contains the media caption. You can decide to hide it by simply unchecking the caption option in the Embed button dialog.This will open a dialog where you can get the HTML embed code. Simply copy the code into your website and the embedded post will automatically load. By default the post contains the media caption. You can decide to hide it by simply unchecking the caption option in the Embed button dialog.

There is also a section further down on that page about embedding them pragmatically again without the need for access tokens.